# electron-builder not including entire dependency in built version

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Electron is giving me 'Error: Cannot find module './constructor/getOptions' when I open my executable. I tracked the error to a dependency I have which has the following file structure:

[image]

My issue is that in the built version of the program, the entire `constructor` folder is missing. The way I look at the built version is by using the command `npx asar extract app.asar ./extracted` to view the files. When I look at this dependency I only see `index.js` being listed there.

[image]

I have checked inside of the `index.js` to see if `getOptions` is being imported and it is. I have tried to import the file using relative and absolute path. I have also made sure that the dependency is not under devDependency as electron-builder ignores that. I'm not really sure what else to do. Does electron-builder have an option to go deeper into the file structure of a dependency?

Here is my package.json section for electron-builder:

```
  "build": {
    "productName": "MintAIO",
    "appId": "aio.mint",
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/ic.png"
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg",
      "icon": "build/ic-mac.png"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might come across this issue in the future, there is a bug with Asar where the directory name `constructor` is for some reason not included when being packaged. I'm not sure what other directory names this might cause this issue, but `constructor` is definitely one of them. To fix this, you can either rename that directory to something else, or specifically leave that one dependency unpacked using the `asarUnpack` option in the build config of electron.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to include files on the build section for example

```
     "build": {
"productName": "MintAIO",
"appId": "aio.mint",
"win": {
  "icon": "build/ic.png"
},
"mac": {
  "target": "dmg",
  "icon": "build/ic-mac.png"
},
 "files": [
  "constructor/*"
]
```

}

I think this will do the trick  ....

Comment: I tried doing `"node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/dist/contructor/*.js"` but I'll give that a try as well. Will it be able to figure out where the `contructor/*` path is from?

Comment: nope I just made an example in your case you should specify the path

Comment: So you should I try `"node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/dist/contructor/*"`, is that what you're saying?

Comment: no just this , 
"files": [
  "hdwallet-provider/**/**/*"
]

Comment: Do I need to specify the node_modules part like this? `"node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/**/**/*"`. I don't understand how it could just find the path without it.

Comment: I tried both and neither one did anything